# Displaying calculated averages for all matches from fixtures list

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database with matches for Championship and want to display a list of upcoming matches and average number of goals in matches for each of the teams from last 5 matches that they were involved in.

E.g.

```
SELECT ko_time, home, away FROM matches_table WHERE ko_time = TODAY
```

will give me something like this.

```
15:00 Blackburn Rovers  Charlton Athletic
15:00 Brentford  Preston North End
15:00 Bristol City  Reading
15:00 Huddersfield Town  Bolton Wanderers
15:00 Hull City  Queens Park Rangers
```

Now, I know how to calculate an average number of goals for one team from their last 5 matches e.g.

```
SELECT AVG(home_score + away_score) FROM matches_table WHERE
home = "Brentford" or away = "Brentford"
ORDER BY match_date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This will give me average number of goals from 5 last matches of Brentford.

Now, I'm not sure how to combine these two queries and have the averages calculated for all teams and displayed like below:

```
15:00 Blackburn Rovers  Charlton Athletic  2.3 2.4
15:00 Brentford  Preston North End 1.4 2.3
15:00 Bristol City  Reading 2.6 0.9
15:00 Huddersfield Town  Bolton Wanderers 3.6 1
15:00 Hull City  Queens Park Rangers 0.8 1.65
```

Anyone has any ideas? Thank you

Attached link to db

[Database](http://speedy.sh/Hn3qA/championship.sql)

Comment: By using JOIN. regex doesn't apply here

Comment: Sorry, regex was added as recommended tag. Could you give an example with JOIN? Thanks

Comment: Your code for the average score does not look right (it gets the average scores for the *matches* not for the *teams*).  You should set up a SQL Fiddle with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It's average number of goals per match of those teams. E.g. 
Brentford 1.4 would be the average number of goals per match from last 5 matches.

Comment: It looks like your table have both matches already played and upcoming ones, so your second query will also include upcoming matches unless you specify that `match_date` should be prior than today. We have the expected output, but we need the table structure and sample data to help you further.

Comment: Thank you. That's correct - the table includes both present and played matches. I edited the main post and added the mysql file with sample data and structure.

Comment: Could anyone help? Thank you